# Need tree view using accordian

Tags: html, angularjs, accordion

I am using Accordian but trying to display tree view

Please find the below sample for reference.
[Preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/vcTiFxkYIRln4asi1DYi?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainController',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      name: "Products",
      desc: "Products",
      subitems: [{
        name: "Pricing",
        desc: "Pricing",
        subitems: [{
          name: "Personal",
          desc: "Personal",
          subitems: [{
            name: "R and d",
            desc: "R and d",

          }]

        }, {
          name: "subitem2",
          desc: "Sub-Item 2"
        }]
      }, {
        name: "Software",
        desc: "Software"
      }, {
        name: "Hardware",
        desc: "Hardware"
      }]
    }, {
      name: "HP",
      desc: "HP",

    }];

    $scope.default = $scope.items[2];
  });
```

I need the accordian to be displayed as below image.

[image]

Comment: why you need to use accordion, create it's with list

Comment: it needs to expand on click and need some animation.